# TFDBatchMove trying to write NULL into a not Null Firebird DB column

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

I'm trying to use Delphi 11.2's TFDBatchMove to make a copy of a record in a Firebird database table. The table contains at least one column which is set to "not null" and a default value for the column is specified.

The reader for the TFDBatchMove is a TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader which gets a TFDQuery assigned to .DataSet. That query selects all the columns to copy, which excludes the "not null" column!

The Write for the TFDBatchMove is a TFDBatchMoveSQLWriter, which only gets the DBConnection assigned and the correct TableName.

At runtime I get an exception on .Execute of the TFDBatchMove:

First chance exception at $7720E292. Exception class EIBNativeException with message
'[FireDAC][Phys][FB]validation error for column "MEINE_TABELLE"."MEINE_SPALTE", value "*** null ***"'. Process MeineExe.exe (6728)

How to prevent it trying to write to that column?

Answer (score 0):

I meanwhile found out that the writer has already some event assigned where I can modify the data written based on which column it tries to write to and there I can (and even need to) set a value for that not null colmum which differs from the default specified in the database anyway.

So one can either "close" this question as "resolved" or wonder why the TFDBatchMove seemingly tries to write null into that column, which was not in the select clause of the reader instead of letting the DB use the default value set up.

Comment: Isn't "because Delphi developers wrote it this way" an obvious answer? They are human beings and not totally geniuses, you know... You can read sources of VCL and fix them.

Comment: Well, it's not in the VCL source but the FireDAC one. I have a similar problem now, but in my case the OnNewRecord is never called! It's this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77581176/why-is-my-onnewrecord-event-during-the-batchmove-execute-never-called