# Why is my OnNewRecord event during the BatchMove.Execute never called?

Tags: delphi, firedac

I use FireDAC's BatchMove to copy the data from one table to another one.
In order to sol problems with not NULL columns I wanted to assign an OnNewRecord
eventhandler to the FWriter.FDDataSet.OnNewRecord.

But that one is never called!
Anybody any clues why it is never called?

```
  constructor TDBCopy.Create;
  begin
    inherited;
    ... 
    FBatchMove.Writer               := FWriter;
    FWriter.Connection              := FTargetSQLConnection;
    FWriter.FDDataSet.OnNewRecord   := OnNewRecord;
  end;
```

and

```
procedure TDBCopy.OnNewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  ... // this code is never called
end;
```

and

```
FWriter.TableName := TableName;
FBatchMove.Execute;
```

Which is executed in a TTask.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I learned now, that a SQLWriter won't fire this event.